# getvalue() error field not get values

Tags: magento2, session

Fields not getting values in return array.

$0.00

Please, someone, review my code.

```
public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
{

   global $value1;
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
   $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
   $customerSession->setValue($value1); //set value in customer session
  $vluas= $customerSession->getValue($value1);
  //print_r($vluas);

  //echo $vluas;

    return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => 'Fee',
        'value' => $vluas
    ];

}
```

Comment: error getvalue called i want to call just value <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">$0.00</span>
    </td>

Comment: please remove comment from print_r($vluas);

Comment: and share that output

Comment: script shows this
<script>
            window.checkoutConfig = 15 darham{"payment":{"ccform":{"icons":{"AE":{"url":"http:\/\/testing2.dukaania.com\/pub\/static\/version1538805868\/frontend\/MageBig\/martfury_layout01\/en_US\/Magento_Payment\/images\/cc\/ae.png","width":46,"height":30},"VI":

Comment: i want this calue to show 15 darham

Comment: got you, print_r($vluas[0]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84114/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-jhon-jhon-doe).

Answer (score 0):

You should set and get value as below

```
$customerSession->setValue($value1); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();
```

Comment: field return this
<span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">$0.00</span>
when i set your code
$customerSession->setValue($value1); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();
//print_r($vluas);

//echo $vluas;

        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => $vluas
        ];